# RegEx: Catch block start with "something" in a text

Tags: regex

I need a regex to chatch 2 groups: Success (the start of text block) and all the folow, untill next Success
Text sample with 3 success block:

```
Success        blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla

Success        blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla
blablabla 

blablabla
blablabla blablabla


Success        blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla  blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla 



blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla
```

This regex stop the block to first `\n`:

```
(Success|Error|Critical|Warning)\s{8}((.*|\n*?|\r*?|[\r\n]*?)*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many possibilities would be (with `multiline`, `verbose` and `singleline` enabled):

```
^(Success|Error|Critical|Warning)
.+?
(?=^(?:Success|Error|Critical|Warning)|\Z)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/PnzNkL/2/).